# Jasmine: Mock parent class so I could isolate and test the son class

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test, testbed

I have the following scenario:

```
export class HttpClientService extends Http {...}    
export class AppHttpClientService extends HttpClientService {...}
```

What I want is to override the `HttpClientService` to a mock class so I could make tests only on functions present on `AppHttpClientService`.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

using TestBed, you can provide a mock to your service, like `HttpClientServiceMock`

your mock could be a simple class declared like for example:

```
class HttpClientServiceMock {
  get(url) {
    ...
  }
}
```

and then use `TestBed.overrideComponent` to override the service that your component use.

**example:**

```
TestBed.overrideComponent(AppHttpClientService, {
  set: {
    providers: [{ provide: HttpClientService, useValue: HttpClientServiceMock}]
  }
});
```

The last example is for overriding a service. To do the same for a component you can try:

```
TestBed.overrideComponent(ParentComponent, {
  set: {
    template: '<span>{{data}}</span>'
  }})
  .createComponent(ParentComponent);
```

This way you will use only some part you want, for your original parent component, to use in the test.

And now when you will create an instance for your child component, it will use this overridden version of the parent component.